# Paths in Windows and Mac

Tags: python, path

I have a csv file where it is written filename and path of my data in this form in Python

data_path=folder/folder2/file.txt

I am working now on a windows workstation and windows has path in this form

```
my_path=C:\User\Folder...
```

so if I try to run

```
load(my_path+data_path)
```

I got error because says: it is not possible to find  C:\User\Folder\folder/folder2/file.txt

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the *exact* code? What is the *exact* error message? The path you’ve shown is an entirely valid Windows path, and Python has no problem with it. The answers below are correct in that you should use a library to work with paths instead of representing them as strings … but using string concatenation *works* in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for concatenating paths, use `os.path.join`.

```py
import os
load(os.path.join(my_path, data_path))
```

Comment: This is definitely good practice (pathlib would be even better) but it won’t fix OP’s issue, which is caused by an incorrect path, not by incorrect concatenation (actually, it might well be; OP’s error message is not correct, and details are lacking).

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.4 introduced a new standard library for dealing with files and paths called pathlib.you just pass a path or filename into a new Path() object using forward slashes and it handles the rest. Simple example of 'open' below using pathlib.

More info here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

```
from pathlib import Path

data_folder = Path("source_data/text_files/")
file_to_open = data_folder / "raw_data.txt"
f = open(file_to_open)
print(f.read())
```